# identify and delete PDF Files that have duplicate information

Tags: pdf, duplicates

I have a large number of PDF files from user resumes (about 10 thousand), among them there are items that have duplicate and same information of a person, but the content display format may be different (Because the same user information has been exported from different sites). How can I identify and delete Pdf files that have duplicate information (such as mobile  number or email address) but the content display format is different

I wish you the best

Comment: Probably you're looking for an OCR system that extract you the text. After you extracted the text evaluate it in order to isolate the informations despite the display. What system are you adoperating? What language? Are pdf always compilable or scanned? Some other informations could be nice in order to write a complete answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert on PDF files, but to my knowledge they generally work in one direction. E.g once it is PDF you can't go back.

Adobe Acrobat DC works around this by utilizing machine learning (more specifically OCR) to enable editing. Here is a link to their website and their explanation: https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/how-to/ocr-software-convert-pdf-to-text.html

I found that they have an API which probably resembles what you are after: https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/apis/pdf-services/

So step one would be to get the information of the pdf in some text format.

Can the duplicated information be anything or is it something that is easily recognizable? Phone number and email address should be easy to find within the text using awk, grep or regex. Once you have located the "information" within two files you can just compare the text and see if they are equal or not, which will determine whether the document should be deleted.

Maybe someone can provide a more straight forward practical solution, but here you have a high level idea for a solution until then.

Comment: thanks for your comment ، yes there is duplicated information can be easily recognizable like national code or mobile phone but need a windows app to detect and remove duplicate PDF files